# (How) Can I make a page which is the only page on a printed sheet?

Tags: pdf, printing, viewers, postscript

I want to make a PDF document which have no blank pages when viewed or printed single-sided.  But when printed double-sided, the first page (the cover) should be the only page printed at the first sheet.  Is it possible at all?

Also, is it possible to make every section/chapter begin on a new sheet without inserting blank pages (that are visible in PDF viewer or in single-sided print)?

Would use of PostScript as format of the final document help somehow?

At the moment I use:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{doi}
```

The document is compiled with calling `pdflatex` twice.

But do not let my current setup constrain you in any way.  I may adapt and even start from scratch if necessary.

Comment: Hello @abukaj To help us providing good answers, can you tell us at least the document class you are using, the main packages you load for that document, and your compilation workflow/chain?

Comment: @gildux I updated the question.  The moment the compilation chain is complicated, as the cover is added to the output pdf with pdftk, but I may as well add it as an image or so.  The main question is whether what I want is possible at all in PDF/PS file?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example with the class `book` to be able to use the chapters.

When using the `twoside` option, the redefinition of `\cleardoublepage` will suppress the blank page after the first page. All chapters will start on a new page (as always) odd or even instead of always odd, so no extra blank page will be generated.

The `twoside` option will generate the same number of pages as `oneside`. Only the margins will change.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
    
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else\hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}% added <<<<<<<<<<
    
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% dummy text

\begin{document}
    \kant[1]
    \chapter{First}
    \kant[2]
    \chapter{Second}
    \kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Comment: I have tried the example. Sadly it does not work - okular prints pages 1 and 2 at opposite sides of the same sheet.